# Differences between forwarding and redirect in net.inet.ip

Tags: bsd, sysctl

What are the differences between sysctl variables `net.inet.ip.forwarding` and `net.inet.ip.redirect`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting ip_forwarding to 1 enables the kernel to route packets. Basically your host will become a router. Setting ip_redirect to zero disables the kernel to sending or receiving icmp-redirects, which will occur if some host (or this host) finds a better route for a packet.